# Bootstrap Datepicker and changeDate Events with multiple Date Pickers in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a table with a Data Picker on each row with a dynamically generated ID for each Date Picker. I currently have a script that fires when the date is changed, but I've discovered that this is also firing when users use the keyboard to edit this input field.

I could change to use the [changeDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event but not sure how this works with multiple date pickers when I can't specify the ID for each date picker? Another option would be to prevent users from modifying the data directly using the keyboard but not sure if that is possible?

Here's an example of how my table currently looks:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".form-control.datepicker").change(function() {
        alert("starting Date Updated Changes");
        //console.log( 'starting Date Updated update' );
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-AU.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    autoclose: true
  })
</script>

<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="70283">
      <td>FT523452</td>
      <td>X234</td>
      <td>Container Oranges</td>
      <td>534830</td>
      <td class="">ZDSFASDF42234</td>
      <td>Transit</td>
      <td id="70283"><input type="text" id="70283" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date Updated" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateUpdated"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="70543">
      <td>PB213412</td>
      <td>Z98787</td>
      <td>Container Apples</td>
      <td>535092</td>
      <td class="">PSDFKS42134</td>
      <td>Transit</td>
      <td id="70543"><input type="text" id="70543" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date Updated" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateUpdated"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker();
      $(".form-control.datepicker").change(function(e) {
       console.log(e);
        alert("starting Date Updated Changes");
        //console.log( 'starting Date Updated update' );
      });      
});
```